# A method to pass a variable to Javascript currently run in the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Please excuse me ignorance, I'm completely new to Javascript.

I have this code that is currently run in the header, however I need to pass it `$_GET`  variables before it runs.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
refresh();

jQuery('#bittrex-price').load('http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php?symbol=ltc');
jQuery('#mintpal-price').load('http://<site>/realtime/mintpal-realtime.php?symbol=ltc');
});

function refresh() {

   setTimeout( function() {
        jQuery('#bittrex-price').fadeOut('slow').load('http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php?symbol=ltc').fadeIn('slow');
        jQuery('#mintpal-price').fadeOut('slow').load('http://<site>/realtime/mintpal-realtime.php?symbol?ltc').fadeIn('slow');
        refresh();

   }, 10000);
}
```

It's pretty simple, all it does is pull the latest price from another PHP script.

I need to append a `$_GET` variable to the URL as current I have no way to change the `?symbol=ltc` depending on which page the user is visiting. Because Wordpress is being awkward, I've had to save this function in a .js file and add a hook in functions.php otherwise it won't load at all. Ideally, I'd like to be able to run the function in the body so I can modify, but I can't get that to work either :/

I hope this makes sense, I'm open to any suggestions as I'm clearly missing the point somewhere here.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense. I have no idea what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the language that is building the web page to output some javascript for use in your functions.

Thus, if you're using PHP to build your page you could do something like this in the <head> section of your page:

```
<?php
print '<script>';
print 'var symbol = ' . $_GET['your_get_variable'] . ';';
print '</script>';
?>
```

Then, in your later javascript code you have your GET variable string stored in 'symbol' and can use it however you like.

The 'your_get_variable' is what is coming in via the query string in the URL that got you to the current page.  Just make sure you put this code above where you want to use 'symbol' in your later javascript.

Also, It's not really a good idea to use $_GET data directly like that without some validation, but I'm just keeping the example clean.